# How to simulate users in .csv files as thread counts in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a .csv file which has 100 users. Is there a way where i can simulate thread group and thread count to read each user and from .csv file and do the http request operation and loop and pick the second user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure JMeter to generate as many threads as you have rows in your CSV file you can use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for this like:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().size(),)}
```

The function can be placed directly in "Number of Threads" section of the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

[image: JMeter Groovy Function Number of Threads Test Plan]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I am still confused. As i have 100 users in .csv file to hit a GET rest APIso every time one user is picked and injected to api and i am getting the response. and if i add thread count as 1 will it be 1 user hitting the api or 100 users from .csv hitting the api ? Because i do not see any result in jenkins too.

Comment: let me be more specific. Is 100 users from .csv file = number of thread counts by default?